# Is it possible to create more than one admin interface in Django?

Tags: django, django-admin

I asked a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3727605/accessing-various-schemas-in-django-admin-interface). I didn't get many useful answers. May be the question was confusing. So to make it simple, I have different databases used by different users. I want to create a separated admin interface for each of them so that the users will see and modify only the tables related to them. For various reasons multi-db option is not working for me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

django has a feature which allows restriction of tables to specific users. i suggest you look into django.contrib.auth and it's inbuilt permissions.
If you require the ability to completely block access to specific admin sections, you can override the behaviour of the admin site in your admin.py